# how to activate ssl credit for addon domain on godaddy?

Tags: ssl, https

I have two domains on GoDaddy, the primary domain and an addon domain. I purchased SSL credit and would like to activate the ssl on the addon domain, so i used the button "Use SSL Credit" on the CPanel, but a message appears saying "This makes your primary domain more secure by encrypting user data."

I want to activate the SSL for the addon domain, so i tried to change the primary domain on my account, but i got the message "cannot change main domain to addon domain" what should I do to activate the SSL for the addon domain?

I tried contacting their support, but i didn't get a response.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a UCC certificate which can work on multiple domains.

Here's the thread which talks about this:

https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Install-SSL-certificate-on-addon-domain/td-p/32042

You can get the Godaddy UCC certificate from here:

https://in.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate/multi-domain-san-ssl-certificate

Or if you want it to be free, you can opt for [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) Certificate.